# How to disable additional USB keyboards from functioning?

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, group-policy

We want to protect our company against malicious USB devices that act as keyboards.  Of course we can block all USB devices, but this leaves us with the problem that the majority of our users use a external keyboard on their laptop.
We can also use some hardware USB locks, but we found this to be impractical for our laptops.

How can we disable the installation of additional USB keyboards without disabling a certain vendor ID (or the already installed keyboard)? It would be  preferable if this can be done through a group policy.

Comment: Your users, by group policy and other typical security measures, shouldn't be allowed to run scripts no matter where they come from. A malicious script they download or try to run from local storage is no less potentially harmful than the same running from those USB dongles posing as HID.

Comment: @MichaelBay: the point is; when an USB stick is acting as a keyboard, it will easily be able to (e.g.) delete files from, lets say `my documents` folders. This can happen by only inserting the USB stick in the laptop. Although damage will be limited to the current user's access rights, it is  annoying damage. That's why we want to disable it.